# Best way to get a rotating Secrets Manager secret to Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-parameter-store

I'd like to setup a rotating token in Secrets Manager. Our app however uses environment variables from Parameter Store. I need to reference this updated token in our app.

What's the best way to have my app get the updated token? Maybe every 30 days or whatever the rotation period is. Is it a scheduled lambda?

Answer (score 2):

Parameter Store parameters can [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/integration-ps-secretsmanager.html) Secret Manager secrets. This means that you can save a value in AWS Secrets Manager and use the rotation provided by it. As long as your secret is not an RDS, DocumentDB or Redshift secret, you will have to create a Lambda function for rotation (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html)).

Although, the solution above would work, it might be simpler to have a the value saved in SSM Parameter Store encrypted and simply use a Lambda function with a CloudWatch [scheduled event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) to rotate it.